# Using colorbox in an iframe

Tags: colorbox

I use colorbox plugin in my iframe. I would like to open it in parent window when i click a button. But the problem is that it opens in iframe's window. I couldn't find any solution yet. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are on the same domain, you can use the parent object in the iframe to open a colorbox in the parent window. (Something like parent.$('#id').colorbox() should work.)

If your iframe is on a different domain, I'm pretty sure you're out of luck due to cross-domain policy restrictions.

Comment: Unfortunately it still opens in iframe. Also when i use parent, the window is no longer in colorbox look, just  normal page opening in the frame...

Comment: I've solved it. Create a function then put this code 
window.parent.$.colorbox({href:url, iframe: true, scrolling: false, width: "1250px", height: "600px"});
it works fine!